# Force-directed layout implementation in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, force-layout, force-based-algorithm

Are you aware of an open source implementation of [force-directed layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms) in C++ used for GUIs? Preferably BSD/MIT/Apache or other (non-GPL) license.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The excellent [Boost.Graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) provides a wide range of algorithms, among which a few layout algorithms. I'd recommend using either [Kamada-Kawai spring layout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.html) or [Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed layout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/fruchterman_reingold.html).

[Boost licence](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt) is very permissive so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 8):

The first Google result is [VTK](http://vtk.org/). Another takes me to [vtkGraphLayoutView](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGraphLayoutView.html).

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It is Open Source, free and has a BSD license.

Comment: Having used VTK, I think it's really good solution to your problem. Plus it's fully cross platform Linux/Mac/Windows. 
AND it has binding for Python/Java and tcl/tk in case you ever need them.

Comment: I gotta agree, VTK is superior - the 'GraphItem' example does exactly what the OP requests. Boost::Graph, while an amazing part of the amazing Boost ecosystem is the under-the-hood engine that you have to craft a UI on top of. VTK has everything under one roof and can get you adding vertexes and edges to an animated+springy force-directed graph in less than an hour.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [neato](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/neatoguide.pdf) from [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). This [guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf) even goes into detail for using graphviz as a library. The [guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf) includes using the fdp layout algorithm, which appears to be exactly what you want. All of graphviz falls under the [Common Public License](http://www.graphviz.org/License.php).

Answer (score 2):

OverView

https://www.kitware.com/InfovisWiki/index.php/Main_Page

There are some installation steps if you want this application, all of the info is on that wiki. It is an application built on VTK. The specific function OverView has is the ability to represent a graph of information (not necessarily geometric) in 2 dimensions.

As pointed out by dirkgently, VTK has a force directed graph layout. The benefit of using something like OverView is that you can easily make a custom plug-in for OverView, which you would make to read your data and display it using the force directed layout strategy.

If you don't want to depend on OverView it is very easy to extract your plug-in code and only reference OverView since all of the rendering is handled outside of your plug-in.