# Force-directed layout implementation in Java

Tags: java, directed-graph

I've been looking around for a Java implementation of the force-directed graph layout algorithm but got no fruits so far. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Same question, but for C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713701/force-directed-layout-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jung:

http://jung.sourceforge.net/index.html

.. has been around for a while, and has many layout algorithms.

You might also check out Gephi at http://gephi.org/ - it's an application, not a lib, but it's open source Java.

There's also Processing (a Java superlanguage) and the physics lib here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~traer/physics/random_arboretum/index.html (click in the box a bunch of times to create the graph).

Comment: I agree.  Jung is excellent.  I compared a LOT of Java directed-graph libraries for a work project, and Jung is the best by far.

Comment: I nearly forgot Prefuse! http://www.prefuse.org/ - it's not very active, but I've had good results with the Flash port of Prefuse called Flare.

Answer (score 1):

My searching brought up four closely-related results; I don't know what you need it for, but hopefully at least one of them will be helpful:

- [Force-based graph project](http://code.google.com/p/force-based-graph/) in Java at Google Code
- [Force-directed map labeling](https://www.ads.tuwien.ac.at/research/labeling/)
- [Force-directed map overlays](http://www.luchemos.org.ar/rodrigo/tesis/regions.htm)
- The link I posted in the comment brought up [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/), whose website does claim some support for Java though I haven't researched it thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you Lord Torgamus, I'll check them. You guys are of great help :)